# 'pass' statement in python3 seems to fail

Tags: python

My code is as follows below. I've ensured that the re.match conditional does match, however the pass statement seems to fail as the f.write statement writes each line in the file. What am I missing with the use of pass?

```
with open(bash_file, "r+") as f:
   d = f.readlines()
   f.seek(0)
   for i in d:
       if re.match("alias\ {}".format(instance_name),i):
           pass
       f.write(i)
   f.truncate()
```

Comment: `pass` is not doing what you think it's doing. I think you're looking for `continue` or `break`

Answer (score 3):

`pass` is a placeholder that means "do nothing, then continue as if the `pass` weren't here" (it exists to allow you to use a block introducing statement, like `if`, controlling no actual code; Python's syntax requires at least one indented statement in a block, and using `pass` provides that), so execution continues to the `f.write(i)` call. You want `continue`, which says "skip the rest of this loop and continue with the next item".

In other circumstances (where a mismatch should end the loop entirely), you'd use `break`, but given you seem to only want to skip one `write` for each match, `continue` is the way to go.

Of course, for this particular case, you could just invert the test and control the `write` that way, no need for `continue`, e.g.:

```
for i in d:
    if not re.match("alias\ {}".format(instance_name),i):
        f.write(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass is simply an operator that does nothing. Often times pass is only used as an placeholder. To solve this simply use an continue instead of pass

```py
with open(bash_file, "r+") as f:
   d = f.readlines()
   f.seek(0)
   for i in d:
       if re.match("alias\ {}".format(instance_name),i):
           continue
       f.write(i)
   f.truncate()
```

Comment: [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) is a statement, not an operator